# Why doesnt this ArrayList work for Wave files? (java)

Tags: java, arraylist, wav

I'm trying to create code to get wav files into an array list and then for the arraylist to play the files. Why does this code not work? Thanks.

```
public class trackList {

    public void tracklist(){

        ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList();
        songs.add("c:\\01.wav");
        songs.add("c:\\02.wav");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        for(int x = 0; x < songs.size(); x++){

          try{

                AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songs(x));
                AudioFormat format = ais.getFormat();
                SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(format);
                line.open(format);
                line.start();

          while (ais.available() > 0) {

                int len = ais.read(buffer);
                line.write(buffer, 0, len);

               }

            line.drain(); 
            line.close();

                } 
          catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                }
        }                       
    } 
}
```

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? Does it explode?

Comment: Or does it make monkeys fall on your head? I just *hate* when my programs do that.

Comment: Nothing quite that extreme. songs is not recognised on this line; AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songs(x));

Comment: Plese edit the question to include relevant error messages.  Editing the question is much better than adding comments.  That being said, it looks like a bonafide Java expert has already found your error.

Answer (score 6):

Not a Java expert, but probably the line:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songs(x));
```

Must be

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(songs.get(x));
```

Comment: This makes the entire line underlined